# 押されたキー毎に区別してカウント

Tags: javascript

javascript初心者です。
押されたキー毎にカウントをしたいのですが、

例）rを押した回数だけAの欄に、lを押した回数だけBの欄に0からカウントアップ

どのように設定すればいいのでしょうか？

テキストの書き換えも考えましたが、コードがかなり長くなってしまいそうで不安です。
（↓こちらのサイト様を参考にしております。
http://www.pori2.net/js/DOM/2.html）

何かヒントでもいただけないでしょうか？
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございました！！！（）が閉じられてなかったりでかなり時間がかかりましたが無事解決いたしました！！完成まで至ったのは初めてなので本当に感動しています！！ご教授感謝します。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

既にご存知のことも多いかと思いますが、以下のコードで一通り説明させてください。

まず、「キーが押されたら何をする」というような「～が起きたら～をする」というパターンはイベントに関数を結びつけて記述します。これがdocument.body.onkeydown = function(){//略 };の部分です。これはonkeydown(キーが押されたときで、この時点ではどのキーか区別していない)が起こったらfunction(){}が呼び出されるという意味です。

keydownのようなイベントが起こると、イベントの詳細情報がfunction(){}に渡されて実行されます。ここではそのイベントの詳細情報をeventとして渡しています。

functionの中でどのキーが押されたかの判定をしています。'r'が押されたときにはevent.keyCodeが82, 'l'の時には76になるので、これで判別できます。いずれのキーでもないときには処理がなされません。

次にr, lがそれぞれ何回押されたかを表示するまでを説明します。count_right, count_leftとありますが、これがプログラム中でr, lがそれぞれ押された回数を保持しています。キーが押されるとこれらをインクリメントしているわけです。

r, lの押下回数を表示する部分は、htmlに用意してあって、document.getElementByIdによってr, lそれぞれのための入れ物を取得しています。count_right, count_leftが変更された後にここの値をtextContentをいじることによって変更しています。

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script>
  window.onload = function(){
    var count_right = 0;
    var count_left = 0;
    var right = document.getElementById('right');
    var left = document.getElementById('left');
    right.textContent = count_right;
    left.textContent = count_left;
    document.body.onkeydown = function(event){
      console.log(event.keyCode);
      if(event.keyCode == 82){
        count_right++;
        right.textContent = count_right;
      }
      if(event.keyCode == 76){
        count_left++;
        left.textContent = count_left;
      }
    };
  };
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div>
    rの回数:<span id="right"></span>
  </div>
  <div>
    lの回数:<span id="left"></span>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

ここで使った関数、は「keydown イベント」などとググれば出てくると思いますので、読んでみると使い方がより分かるかもしれません。また、jqueryを使っているのであれば、window.onloadやdocument.body.onkeydown, textContentなどの部分がもう少しすっきりかけるでしょう。

Answer (score 0):

キーボードからの入力をDOMでハンドリングするには、`keydown,keyup,keypress`といったKeyboardEvent系のイベントをキャッチする方法が一般的です。どのイベントがいいかは目的とする処理、および処理系（ブラウザ）の実装状況を鑑みて選択してください。

```
$elm.addEventListener('keypress', e => ...);
```

このとき、イベントハンドラに渡される第一引数は[KeyboardEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent)オブジェクトで、このオブジェクトのプロパティからどのキーが押されたかを判別できます。たとえば

```
$elm.addEventListener('keypress', e => {
    if (e.key === 'Enter') {
        console.log('Enterキーがおされました');
    }
});
```

この方法を応用すれば、どのキーが何回押されたかをカウントしていくことが可能です。表示方法については主旨から外れますが、表示用のDOMを用意しておいて、カウントアップされたら表示を更新していく、といった方法が簡単です。

以下、サンプルではページ内でキーが入力されたとき、それをカウントして、回数をキーごとに表示します。

```js
const keyCount = {};

window.addEventListener('keypress', e => {
    // キーごとに回数をカウント
    keyCount[e.key] = (keyCount[e.key] || 0) + 1;
    
    // 表示を更新
    document.body.textContent = JSON.stringify(keyCount, null, 4);
});
```

```css
body
{
    white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
press any key...
```